# Return text string in excel between a specified word and character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in need of a formula that will return a varying number of characters between specified text `Network:` and a special character `;` in excel. As an example see below

```
Product Name: XXXX; Cover: Full; Holiday Cover: Not Applicable; Additional Cover: Not Applicable; Network: Essential Access; Excess: £0; Out Of Network: X% (no limit);
```

I want the value "Essential Access" only. Key points to note are the value returned will vary in length and its position within the string will also vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the positioning of each substring can vary and there are more occurences of the word "Network:", this may be a nice task for `FILTERXML()`:

```
=MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"; ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'Network:')]"),10,LEN(A1))
```

Comment: Excellent, this works a treat! Really appreciate the help!